# "Минск-1", "Минск-2", а вместе?

Tags: орфография

В Минске есть два аэропорта. Называются они, соответственно, "Минск-1" и "Минск-2". Тут с написанием проблем нет. А вот как быть, если нужно сказать в целом, употребив обобщающее слово "Минск", а потом уже "1 и 2"? Интересует постановка знаков препинания: дефиса и кавычек. То есть, "аэропорты "Минкс-1 и 2" или "аэропорты "Минск 1 и 2" или обобщать вообще нельзя и нужно писать исключительно "Минкс-1" и "Минск-2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: Минск-1 и Минск-2. Так как это два разных  аэропорта с соответствующим названием : Минск-1 и Минск-2. При обобщающем слове появляется  путаница.Так , не ясно, аэропорты  Минска называются 1-2., или один из аэропортов называется Минск-1, а другой 2. Названия аэропортов в кавычки не заключаются. (см.: Мильчин А.Э., Чельцова Л.К. Справочник издателя и автора: Редакционно-издательское оформление издания. - М.: Олимп: ООО «Фирма «Изд-во АСТ, 1999): аэропорт Внуково, аэропорт Домодедово и т. п.).